# DRYing jasmine nested describe blocks

Tags: javascript, jasmine, specifications, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to test some view code by using jasmine. I need to test the presence of certain elements when the view object is in different inclusive states without having to repeat a lot of code in each state.

I've got the class NodeView which represents a node with some endpoints in order to allow the user to connect this node to other nodes with some lines. Each node is placed into a column (group), so that if this node is placed into the first group, it won't show the left endpoint. If the node is into the last group, it won't show the right endpoint. I can manage this situation using nested describe blocks in jasmine:

```
var node, subject, model;

describe("render", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model = mockModel();
  });

  describe("when the node is into first group", function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
      model.isInFirstGroup.andReturn(true);
      model.isInLastGroup.andReturn(false);

      node = new NodeView(model);
    });

    it("has the left endpoint hidden", function() {
      expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeHidden();
    });

    it("has the right endpoint visible", function() {
      expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeVisible();
    });
  });

  describe("when the node is into last group", function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
      model.isInFirstGroup.andReturn(false);
      model.isInLastGroup.andReturn(true);

      node = new NodeView(model);
    });

    it("has the left endpoint visible", function() {
      expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeVisible();
    });

    it("has the right endpoint hidden", function() {
      expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeHidden();
    });
  });
```

So far everything is ok. The troubles start when we have others different states, in this case this state is allow input. this is a boolean that indicates if the user can draw lines. If this boolean is true, then the node has to contain an 'input' class among other stuffs. Here is the code (render function again):

```
describe("when the node is in input state", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model.input = true;
    node = new NodeView(model);
  });

  it("has the class input", function(){
    expect(node.el).toHaveClass('input');
  });
});

describe("when the node is not in input state", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model.input = false;
    node = new NodeView(model);
  });

  it("has not the class input", function(){
    expect(node.el).not.toHaveClass('input');
  });
});
```

Ok, well, Im testing the generated html markup when building a node (not calling the render method explicitly), but it does this work internally. Render is called when the object is built (the constructor calls render), that's why Im not calling node.render() explicitly in the code.

Testing those different states would require the test to include all possible situations:

- first group - input
- last group - input
- first group - no input
- last group - no input

If I add another boolean state, then Ill have 8 scenarios and so on. I have tried to clean it a little bit by using shared examples http://pivotallabs.com/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior/

```
sharedExamplesForGroupState = function() {
  describe("(shared)", function() {
    describe("when the node is into first group", function() {
      beforeEach(function () {
        model.isInFirstGroup.andReturn(true);
        model.isInLastGroup.andReturn(false);

        node = new NodeView(model);
      });

      it("has the left endpoint hidden", function() {
        expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeHidden();
      });

      it("has the right endpoint visible", function() {
        expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeVisible();
      });
    });

    describe("when the node is into last group", function() {
      beforeEach(function () {
        model.isInFirstGroup.andReturn(false);
        model.isInLastGroup.andReturn(true);

        node = new NodeView(model);
      });

      it("has the left endpoint visible", function() {
        expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeVisible();
      });

      it("has the right endpoint hidden", function() {
        expect(node.el.find('.endpoint .left')).toBeHidden();
      });
    });
  });
});

describe("when the node is in input state", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model.input = true;
    node = new NodeView(model);
  });

  it("has the class input", function(){
    expect(node.el).toHaveClass('input');
  });

  sharedExamplesForGroupState();
});

describe("when the node is not in input state", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model.input = false;
    node = new NodeView(model);
  });

  it("has not the class input", function(){
    expect(node.el).not.toHaveClass('input');
  });

  sharedExamplesForGroupState();
});
```

Lines above don't work as expected because the input state tests are done without setting the input state, so, what we are really testing is:

- input and no input independently of the group
- first and last group without including input test cases, but including the model.input attribute

This isn't really testing the all 4 cases.

Any ideas on how to improve this to avoid exponential repeated code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you found a solution how to dry up the describe blocks?

Answer (score 2):

I think the callback funcion that the beforeEach on your latest describe blocks are registering is being overridden by the beforeEach invocation on the sharedExamplesForGroupState() call. If you create a new scope for the sharedExamplesForGroupState invocation (like enclosing it into a describe block), it should work:

```
describe("when the node is in input state", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    model.input = true;
    node = new NodeView(model);
  });

  it("has the class input", function(){
    expect(node.el).toHaveClass('input');
  });

  describe("shared examples for group state", function() {
    sharedExamplesForGroupState();
  });
});
```

Comment: It was a mistake in the code example. I already fixed it. The question is more like how to avoid tests cases repetition when trying to test states that requires some initial settings that has to be done into a nested beforeEach block. Maybe I could solve it removing all beforeEach block from shared examples and let the top most test declaration to make the needed settings for each combination.